# error when plotting GAM smooths with plot_smooths()

Tags: r, plot, smoothing, gam, random-effects

I'm having trouble with plotting GAM's smoothing terms, using different functions; I believe the problem may be with the model I created but I'm not completely sure.

So, here's the `str()` for the dataset I have:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   4535 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ animals_id   : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ g_med_Lat    : num  49 49 49 49 48.9 ...
 $ social_status: chr  "a_m" "a_m" "a_m" "a_m" ...
 $ month        : num  1 1 4 4 4 4 4 6 6 7 ...
 $ inter_k      : num  4.24 4.76 4.17 4 8 ...
```

And here is the model I built:

```
s_status <- gam(inter_k ~ factor(social_status) + 
                          s(month, k = 12, by=factor(social_status)) + 
                          s(factor(data$animals_id), bs="re"), 
                  data=data,  
                  family= Gamma(link="log"),
                  method = "REML")
```

Now, a detail that may be important, if I run the random effect without `factor(data$animals_id)` (so, only with `factor(animals_id)`), **I get this error**:

```
Error in factor(animals_id) : object 'animals_id' not found
```

Examples of following errors when plotting the anything connected with the smooths, using the model `s_status` as mentioned above:

**1)** using the plot_smooths() function, following the first plot in [this webpage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidymv/vignettes/plot-smooths.html).

> ```
>  > plot_smooths(model = s_status, series = month, comparison = social_status) + theme(legend.position = "top")
>     
>  Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'animals_id' not found
>  In addition: Warning message:
>  In predict.gam(model, fitted_df, se.fit = TRUE, exclude = exclude_these) :
>       not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!
> ```

**2)** using the plot_smooth() function, following the first plot in [this webpage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidymv/vignettes/plot-smooths.html).

> ```
> > plot_smooth(s_status, view='month', plot_all='social_status', rm.ranef=TRUE)
> Error in `[.data.frame`(x$model, , i) : undefined columns selected
> ```

**3)** using the compare_smooths() function, where I wanted to compare smooths from different models (created with different datasets):

> ```
> > comp <- compare_smooths(s_status_1, s_status_2, s_status_3)
>
> Error: Some smooths in 'select' were not found in model `X[[i]]`:
>   s(factor(inter_kill_2$animals_id)), s(factor(inter_kill_3$animals_id))
> ```

So, I'm guessing this is connected with having `animals_id` as a random effect but I'm not sure why, and I'm also not sure how to fix it (if it's fixable, or if I just need to remove it...)

Any thoughts?

Comment: For starters, convert your data to factors *before* you fit your model so you don’t need all those `factor()` calls

Comment: I did that, but it only worked with factor() within the model

Comment: Then you have a different problem as it will work (I've fitted thousands of GAMs with mgcv and it has now problem with factors in your data and indeed expects them). But the problem with terms like `factor(x)` in formulas is that anything trying to read that formula from the mgcv object has to work very hard to find the data or names of variables you are smoothing because it's hard to tell if you really had a variable named `factor(x)` or a variable `x` that you convert to factor when evaluating the model frame when fitting the GAM.